# PPA efforts only create an empty build directory with pbuilder or ppa itself

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, ppa, debuild

I successfuly built a debian package with no errors. However pbuilder and my ppa upload does not copy files to /opt/ directory. I have the following tree:

```
├── opt 
│   └── myDir
│       └── myfile
└── DEBIAN
    ├── control
    ├── postinst
    └── preinst   and many more ....
```

I have created the template using `dh_make` and edited postinst, copyright, control etc.

I thought `/opt` will be automatically cloned to my `/opt` upon installation. This is the case when I build my package using `debuild -us -uc` and install that package using `dpkg -i`, but unfortunately does not happen when I check the output of pbuilder or my ppa. Only an empty build directory in `/opt/myDir` is created. I am willing to give any more information in case needed. Any guidance is appreciated.

Some information are as follows:

1. debian/control file

   ```
   Source: myproj
   Section: utils
   Priority: optional
   Maintainer: My Name <myname...>
   Build-Depends: debhelper (>=9), sudo, qtbase5-dev, qtchooser, qt5-qmake, qtbase5-dev-tools, gksu, nmap, xterm, fontconfig
   Standards-Version: 3.9.6
   Homepage: <mygit..>
   #Vcs-Git: git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/myproject.git
   #Vcs-Browser: https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/myproject.git

   Package: mypackage
   Architecture: any
   Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
   Description: descriptions
   ```
2. `postinst`: is a bash script that compiles Qt project in target `/opt/myDir`
3. I haven't touched `rules` file.
4. `copyright` is well established.

`debuild` gives some warnings but no errors. Please help me solve the original problem of /opt not being cloned to the target filesystem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Probably you are using a custom build location, so debian helper couldn't figure out automatically where are the files.
- `DEBIAN`?!!! in capital that mean this is a binary Debian package, Are you sure this is pre-built binary. Otherwise rename it to `debian`  or recheck documentation.
- If you don't want changing build rules for files location. Write a  `debian/<packagename>.install` file which map each folder or file (in build tree) to the correct location for installation. For example, if you want to copy the `source-package/opt` to `/opt` after installation, the contents of this file should be

  ```
  opt/* opt
  ```

Ref: [Debian Maintainer Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html)